# Is there a short $BUILD_ID in Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-build

I'd like to use the build ID in a step in Cloud Build.

I'm looking at variables available at https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values but I'm not seeing anything other than `$BUILD_ID` that I can use but that takes up 36 characters.

Is there a short version I'm missing?  There's a SHORT_SHA for the Git SHA for each commit.       So I thought there might be one for the build ID.